# Nexus 4 disconnecting from Mac after 1 minute while in dev mode

Tags: android

I just installed the Android SDK on my Mac. When I connect my Nexus 4 phone (running 4.3) via USB, it shows up using the monitor tool, but after a minute, it disappears.  Once it's gone, `adb devices` fails to show it as well.

I have turned on developer mode and since it shows up for a minute, I assume all that is working correctly.

The device is not going to sleep and the screen is not dimming. I can't figure out why it's disconnecting.

Any ideas? Is it something on the Mac side that's killing it? Nothing is showing up on the Mac's console logs when it disconnects.

Comment: Make sure you do not have multiple instances of `adb` running simultaneously.

Comment: No, there is only one adb process running.

Comment: Try to connect your device to another USB port.

Comment: Switch USB ports seemed to work, but once I try to transfer data via `adb install`, it disconnects.

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB cable? it might be damaged.